# Azure Static Web App - staticwebapp.config.json file MimeTypes

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, mime-types

I have a very basic Azure Static Web App with a full screen video background

Page loads fine on my computer and video plays but does not display the video via the Azure web page - poster image displays OK though

I believe this is to do with setting the Mime Type

The site does not have a web.config

I have read that it needs a staticwebapp.config.json file ([Configure Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#example-configuration-file))

I have included this in the root of the site but still no video?

This is the content of the .json file

```
   {
      "mimeTypes": {
        ".mp4": "video/mp4",
        ".webm": "video/webm"
      }
    }
```

This is the section of code from the html file that has the video

```
<video autoplay  poster="images/poster.png" id="videobg" loop>
      <source src="images/video.webm" Type="video/webm">
      <source src="images/video.mp4" Type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I am sure this is something simple but could not find anything Googling

thanks for any advice

Comment: What do you see in browser tools (networking/console tabs)?

Comment: Hi there - thanks for the reply - there were some errors relating to http (google fonts path in .css) but i have fixed those - no errors in the console or network tabs now - still no video

Comment: Can you share the actual link for your app?

Comment: its just a test - with code pulled from internet - I will clean up once video working - https://happy-mushroom-085d45e1e.1.azurestaticapps.net

Comment: Thanks. Can you add "controls" attribute to your `video` tag? Something like `<video autoplay  poster="images/poster.png" id="videobg" loop controls">`. I was able to play the video that way.

Comment: still no go after that update :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242558/discussion-between-pelagos-and-gaurav-mantri).

Comment: Hmmm...weird. Can you try that in a different browser? Could be related to browser caching.

Comment: I have tried in Chrome and Safari - on 2 separate computers and phone. Just to reiterate - it does work locally on my machine - just not when viewed via the Azure site

Comment: Unfortunately I have no clue. Sorry!

Answer (score -4):

So this is working now

I copied some code from a different location and it is working

not sure what fixed it but thanks

Comment: what code did you copy?